# Firebase Auth always nil

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to Auth users with email but my function always return nil user. it worked perfectly until I added Facebook sign in as well, I made sure that I'm logged out of my facebook user when I try to register a new user to firebase. 
Please let me know if any more of my code is needed to answer this.

```
Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: pass, completion: { 
   (user, error) in
   if user != nil {
       print ("registered")
       self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToHome", sender: self)
   } else {
       print("Error")
   }
})
```

Comment: Did you enabled the email password auth in firebase console?

Comment: Yes. It is enabled

Comment: Any thing(error) relevant in log?

Comment: nothing in particular

Comment: If you replace `print ("Error")` with `print (error)` the logs may show what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `if user != nil` do `if (error != nil)` and have your success code in the else statement.